# ASP.Net Friendly URL 404 error in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-routing, visual-studio-2015, friendly-url

So I have an ASP.Net web forms project.

Global.asax.cs contains:

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
}
```

And RouteConfig.cs has:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    var settings = new FriendlyUrlSettings();
    settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;
    routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Got inside registerroutes.");
}
```

Seems like those are the things I need for friendly url's to work.  And any address I visit, like "localhost/Default.aspx", gets turned into a friendly URL, "localhost/Default" in this case.  So that part seems to be working at least.  I also see my little debug statement get spit out, so the RegisterRoutes method is for sure running.

But any friendly style URL (localhost/Default lets say) I try and visit or get redirected to gives me a 404 error.  Can anyone tell me what I'm missing?

Comment: Shouldn't it be routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings)

Comment: Are you running in IIS express or IIS? IIS Express should have a port number in the URL.

Comment: Yeah, sorry bout that Dylan.  It is "routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings).  I was just commenting out various things trying to get things working and screwed up when I pasted things.

Comment: Yeah, it's IIS express and there is a port number in the URL.  I just left it out for brevity.

Comment: Do you have any ASPX pages in the app? In particular, is there a Default.aspx on disk to run?